# how to export json data on excel sheet using flutter

Tags: excel, api, flutter, dart, export

I have a doubt how to export JSON data in excel sheet using flutter. I tried to JSON data convert to excel sheet using google app script but JSON data dont get manipulate after getting parameters from app to script editor sheet.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good library called [excel](https://pub.dev/packages/excel)

https://pub.dev/packages/excel

Comment: Thanks but could you design whole row like a5 , b5 and so on

Answer (score 0):

Please share code of what you're doing in flutter as well as app scripts.

If you're getting parameters in app script, then you can manipulate them however you want. For that you'll have to write code in app script.

Comment: Now i used excel library from third party libraries on pub dev i.e excel: ^1.1.5. I successfully exported whole json data to excel sheet however it is not allowing to design whole row. Can you help me.

Comment: What do you mean by design whole row?

Comment: Whole row means full excel sheet 1 row for example a1, b1 , c1 and so on

Comment: have you used syncfusion_flutter_xlsio 19.1.63-beta library as well , actually i need to design excel sheet header , first header is at top so i designed that , but after first header some items are there then again header is there , then some items, i hope you understand